# append an extra column to INSERTs from a CSV file

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pypyodbc

I need to append a column/value to the below insert. The value is the same for every row.I can append the column name to the cols tuple, but cannot seem to append the value to the data.I am reading from hundreds of text files of varying format, and the target is sql server table Any help very grateful. THANKS!!!

```
    with open (full_path, 'r',encoding=my_encoding) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=my_delim, quotechar=my_quote)
        cols = next(reader) 
        qry = 'insert into '+ my_table_name +'({0}) values ({1})'
        qry = qry.format(','.join(cols), ','.join('?' * len(cols)))
        cursor = cnn.cursor()
        for data in reader:
           cursor.execute(qry, data)
        cursor.commit()
```

Comment: You don't show appending the new column to `cols` - what does that look like? What value do you want to append to `data`?

Comment: This is the untouched code. I want to add a column and value. Column name is MY_FILE_NUMBER.   value is. 100.     current attempt at APPEND IS.  Cols.append("MY_FILE_NUMBER")    That works, appending value does not.

Comment: I think I got it I think I need to add column name and value as a pair to the COLS tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Since the way you are using [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) returns lists, you can simply append the extra column name to the `cols` list ...

```python
cols = next(reader) + ['MY_FILE_NUMBER']
```

... and append the extra value to the end of the `data` list inside the loop

```python
for data in reader:
    crsr.execute(qry, data + [100])
```